# How does the Windows kernel knows if the kernel memory has been modified?

Tags: windows, kernel

I have read that a blue screen happen in Windows when a buggy device driver modify a part of the kernel memory that it should not modify.

But how does the Windows kernel knows when that part of memory has been modified, does the CPU inform the Windows kernel when that happens?

Comment: Trying to detect a memory modification after the fact is an inferior method.  Modern CPUs have a MMU that can make memory pages/regions read-only or not-writeable.  Any attempt to write or modify such a protected memory triggers an exception.  IOW catch the violation as it happens, rather than after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t believe that it’s a case of the kernel *knowing*
that memory has been modified. 
It’s more a case of the memory modification *causing*
an invalid memory reference, a division by zero,
or something else that causes a system failure.

Comment: The Windows kernel implements numerous methods to secure its own memory from being modified.  This protection can of course be disabled in order to allow greater debugging capabilities.  How the kernel knows depends on how the memory is being modified.